# Regex to match placeholders

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a twig template and I would like to match every placeholder occurence

---

```
Hi {{ user.name }},
this is just an {{ example.name }}
```

---

If I use in php this regex: `/\{{2}([^}]+)\}{2}/`

I will obtain as output not only the placeholders but even the content (so, basically, this)

```
array(
 array(
   0 => {{ user.name }}
   1 => {{ example.name }}
 ),
 array(
   0 => user.name
   1 => example.name
 )
);
```

How can I isolate only the whole placeholder? (So, basically, how can I obtain only first slug of array?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the capturing group. Now, it won't capture the contents present inside the placeholder. So it would leave the first array only.

```
/\{{2}[^}]+\}{2}/
```

Comment: Of course. It was obvious but I'm still sleeping :P